# Cisco PIX 515E Remote SSH

Tags: ssh, cisco, cisco-pix

What configuration lines/steps are required to enable WAN side SSH for the Cisco PIX?  In addition what considerations should be made to ensure your connections are secure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering and downvoting for laziness, because this is clearly a case of LMGTFY:

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/vpndevc/ps2030/products_configuration_example09186a008069bf1b.shtml

Comment: Agree, +1.  Also, @JPrescottSanders, you may want to look at accepting some answers to older questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow the entire internet:

```
ssh 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 waninterfacename
```

Or just a specific host:

```
ssh 77.7.7.7 255.255.255.255 waninterfacename
```

Comment: Are there any other requirements?  This is a "blank slate" scenario.